# 2 http requests on jmeter - each 50% of the time

Tags: random, jmeter, httprequest

I'm trying to create a jmeter script that sends 2 http requests(each with a different path). I managed to get it to send the requests randomly, but i also need it to send each request exactly 50% of the time. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. Divide your requests into 2 separate [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). Set identical number of Threads and Loops in each Thread Group
2. Put 2 requests under the same Thread Group. Add [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) as a child of each request and either set the same "Total Executions" value for both Throughput Controllers or use `50.0` value in "Percent executions" mode.

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for detailed information on above approaches and for more complex distribution scenarios.

Comment: will this be able to send the requests randomly 50% of the time.The first option will execute sequentially.i.e., after one execution stops the next one starts.However for the second option will the request be sent randomly?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Math**

Run a large number of users or a large number of times, picking randomly. On average, it's 50% of the time. Easiest to do, but not exact.

**Option 2: Alternate**

Use a variable to alternate a single thread back and forth over the course of multiple loops. I assume you have some sort of `If Controller` that you're using to split them. In your condition, use `"${alternating_variable}"=="1"`. Then use a `Beanshell Postprocessor` to switch its value: `vars.put(alternating_variable,2);`. Obviously, you'll need the reverse for the other `HTTP Request` (both the `If` and the `Beanshell`). A little involved, and requires a thread to loop multiple times.

**Option 3: Determined by Thread Number**

Inside your `If`, use `${__threadNum}%2!=0` and `${__threadNum}%2==0`. This gets the number of the thread, divides by 2, and compares the remainder to 0. Any even-numbered thread will go into one `If` and any odd thread will go into the other. Easy now that it's generated, but requires multiple threads. Also not necessarily easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Apply 2 throughput controller and place your first http request into first throughput controller and 2nd request in other controller. Now change the mode to `Percent Executions` and pass 50 in throughput textbox

Please refer [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
 link for more details